# Mathematical induction of the harmonics number

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My textbook has the steps to prove it, but I can't comprehend the steps that the textbook are showing. Can someone explain the math or logic used going from steps red to yellow and finally green?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To get from red to yellow, note that
$$(k+1)H_k = (k+1)\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{j}
     = -(k+1)\frac{1}{k+1} + (k+1)\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{j}
     = (k+1)\left(H_{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right).$$
To get from yellow to green, just expand:
\begin{align}
  (k+1) \left(H_{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right) - k + H_{k+1}
      &= (k+1)H_{k+1} - 1 - k + H_{k+1} \\
      &= (k+2)H_{k+1} - 1 - k.
\end{align}

Comment: Wherr did the negative come from for (k+1)?

Comment: To get from the first expression in the first equation to the second, we added $\frac{1}{k+1}$ to the sum (check the indices on the summation). The $-(k+1)\frac{1}{k+1}$ is to correct for that.